# Call to a member function connection() on null during tests

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I want to do performant testing, so I thought about using `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` instead of `TestCase` in my test files. I'm sacrificing http requests testing, but I want at least to use some of the components of Laravel (like its providers and such).

Here's what it looks like :

```
<?php

class ChatTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
        /** @test */
    public function chat_can_be_accepted()
    {
        $this->chat->setStatus(Chat::CHAT_STATUS_WAIT_MASTER);
        $this->chat->accept();

        $this->assertEquals(Chat::CHAT_STATUS_WAIT_CONFIRM, $this->chat->getStatus());
    }
}
```

I have an error saying `Call to a member function connection() on null`. `setStatus` actually uses Laravel internals in this example (something as simple as a relationship that needs the app).

I already tried switching every providers, but it seems code is not even going through providers. Also tried changing PHP versions, or extensions.

Comment: you can find the answer in this issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62843732/6772161

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering my own question for future reminders, and also because I never found this answer anywhere else.

At this point I was using PHPStorm and it doesn't auto load the `phpunit.xml` file when launching tests by default.

That line in the file launches Laravel (works with Lumen too) along with the tests : `bootstrap="bootstrap/app.php"`.

This is needed to use Laravel internals even without using their test frameworks.

To use this in PHPStorm :

[image]

To use this in CLI :

```
phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml
```