# Laravel PHPUnit Call to a member function connection() on null

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am learning testing on Laravel and I am unable to continue testing Eloquent by this error:

Error: Call to a member function connection() on null

This is my code:

```
public function test_users_can_follow_each_other()
    {
        $this->userOne = User::find(1);
        $this->userTwo = User::find(2);
        $this->userOne->followedBy($this->userTwo->id);
        $this->assertTrue($this->userTwo->isFollowedBy($this->userOne->id));
    }
```

I am also using the trait `use DatabaseTransactions;`

The database is already created with 2 records on users table. Do I need to config anything else, thanks!

Comment: How do you create those two records you speak of? If you run tests its usually wiped all out and you need to set up database (records) for each tests.

Comment: First I was using:

$this->userOne = factory(User::class)->create();
$this->userTwo = factory(User::class)->create();

But I got this error:

InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\User].

Comment: Yep, thats how you set up the database for one particular test. So add those two lines in the code. Also change it to `factory(App\User::class, 2)->create()`.

Comment: I still got the same error:

InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\User].

Comment: What Laravel version is this?

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.6, also the factory is working well on tinker. Do I need to make other configurations?

Answer (score 7):

replace

PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase

with

Tests\TestCase